# Fetching data with qraphQL by _id

Tags: node.js, mongodb, graphql

I recently started working with GraphQL. I am able fetch the records from mongodb collections with the base of name, but if I try the same code to get the data by _id(mongodb generated id) I am getting null values for all fields.
Here is my sample code...

```
query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
    // To get a user based on id
      getUser: {
        type: UserType,
        args: {
          _id: {
            description: 'The username of the user',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
          }
        },

       resolve: (root, {_id}) => {
         //Connect to Mongo DB
        return mongo()
            .then(db => { 
             return  new Promise(
              function(resolve,reject){
                 //Query database
                 let collection = db.collection('users');
                 collection.findOne({ _id},(err,userData) => {             
                  if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                    return;
                  } 
                  console.log(userData);
                  resolve(userData);
                });
               })
             });
            }
          },
```

and the sample query is:

```
{ 
      getUser ( _id: "55dd6300d40f9d3810b7f656") 
      {  
               username,
               email,
               password
      } 
}
```

I am getting response like:

```
{
    "data": {
        "getUser": null
    }
}
```

Please suggest me any modifications if required...
Thanq.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because the "_id" field generated by mongoDB is not just a string, it is actually ObjectId("YOUR ID STRING HERE").

So in your query, mongoDB won't find any _id that is equal to the string you feed to it.

Try to use collection.findById() instead.